# wxPython textCtrl silent AppendText

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a text (with several lines) that I need to put in a wxPython TextCtrl.
The problem is that some of these lines are with unprintable characters.

My solution to that was to use AppendText, and try-catch the problematic line.

The current problem is that for a large number of lines it takes a lot of time (relative to preparing a large string with all the lines and using SetValue)

Is there a way to append lines of text to TextCtrl "silently" (so it will not redraw after each line)?

Comment: Why dont you just remove/replace those problematic character and just use SetValue after?

Comment: I don't know the encoding that TextCtrl is trying to use, can I figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [wxTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxtextctrl.html#wxtextctrl) derives from [wxWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindow), it inherits its [Freeze()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowfreeze) and [Thaw()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowthaw) methods.

`Freeze()` will lock screen updates for the control, and `Thaw()` will re-enable them. The documentation actually mentions your very use case, albeit with a caveat:

> This method is useful for visual appearance optimization (for example,
>   it is a good idea to use it before doing many large text insertions in
>   a row into a `wxTextCtrl` under wxGTK) but is not implemented on all
>   platforms nor for all controls so it is mostly just a hint to
>   wxWidgets and not a mandatory directive.